# Function in WITH section, inside view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In the oracle database version 12. Please help me figure out why I get such an exotic error as

> ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel.

I want to create a materialized view, within which the request uses a certain function. That being said, I cannot use the request inside this function. Below is a simplified model (which recreates the error situation).

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_test_view
    BUILD IMMEDIATE
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
  AS
WITH
  function test_func(pInput varchar2) return varchar2 as
    v_output varchar2 (1000);
  begin
    if pInput is null then
      return null;
    end if;
    SELECT 'test'
      into v_output
      FROM dual;
  --  v_output := 'test res';
    return v_output;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return pInput ;
  end;
SELECT test_func('test val') col_1 FROM dual;
```

At the same time, if you move the comment to the request from dual, then the error does not occur.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_test_view
    BUILD IMMEDIATE
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
  AS
WITH
  function test_func(pInput varchar2) return varchar2 as
    v_output varchar2 (1000);
  begin
    if pInput is null then
      return null;
    end if;
  --  SELECT 'test'
  --    into v_output
  --    FROM dual;
    v_output := 'test res';
    return v_output;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return pInput ;
  end;
SELECT test_func('test val') col_1 FROM dual;
```

What can be wrong? Are there any Oracle restrictions?

Comment: Why you should have such an implementation?

Comment: @FarshidShekari This is just a model that shows how the database responds to a request within a function, within a view. The real code is different but has the same problem. The solution for which I want to find.

Comment: Did you check the Alert.log? Whenever I had this error, the server process crashed. Then a look into the Alert.log helps.

Comment: I did a test on an Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production and it just worked. A `SELECT * FROM my_test_view;` returns `test`.

Comment: @D.Mika thank you so much. It means that error is a problem onlfy of our database instance. I'll try to chat with our admins.